# Get highest 3 numbers from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The code below returns the highest number from the array. I am attempting to figure out how to get the top 3 numbers from the array and have been unable to figure it out.

I also am trying to figure out how to list the corresponding jobs with their scores. At the moment the H1 with "Your Highest score was" only shows the number and does not pass through the job (or var name for the highest number).

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h3> Job 95- <span id="score95"> </span> </h3> 
  <h3> Job 96- <span id="score96"> </span> </h3> 
  <h3> Job 97- <span id="score97"> </span> </h3> 
  <h3> Job 98- <span id="score98"> </span> </h3> 
  <h3> Job 99- <span id="score99"> </span> </h3> 
  <h3> Job 100- <span id="score100"> </span> </h3> 
  <h1> Your highest score was: <span id="highest"></span></h1>
</div>
```

JS

```
var job95 = 100;
var job96 = 100;
var job97 = 100;
var job98 = 100;
var job99 = 100;
var job100 = 100;

$( "#no15" ).click(function() {
   console.log('clicked15')
   job95 += 10;
   job96 += 20;
   job97 += 30;
   job98 += 40;
   job99 += 50;
   job100 += 60;
   $('#score95').html(job95);
   $('#score96').html(job96);
   $('#score97').html(job97);
   $('#score98').html(job98);
   $('#score99').html(job99);
   $('#score100').html(job100);

   var numArray = [job95,job96, job97, job98, job99,job100]
   $('#highest').html(Math.max.apply(Math,numArray));
});
```

Comment: Order by score, then take top 3?

Comment: Hey @tomliversidge. Not sure how to do that. Any thoughts on how to get the corresponding job name? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi JS has a built-in `sort` function, what more do you need to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort from lowest to highest and then slice. Example:

```js
var arr = [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3];
//Sort the array from lowest to highest
//Thanks to Charlietfl, I forgot to sort it numerically
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
//Get the highest 3
var top3Arr = arr.slice(-3);
console.log(top3Arr)


//This is an array, so if you want each number individually just access the array

var highest = top3Arr[2];
var secondHighest = top3Arr[1];
var thirdHighest = top3Arr[0];
```

Comment: @charlietfl What do you mean?

Comment: I mean put `11` or `22` in that array and see what sort returns

Comment: Simple cases sometimes overshadow issues like that because it was working with only single digits in array

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @wateriswet! 

A few questions for you. Instead on console.log-ing the result I passed it in my $('#highest3').html(top3Arr). This bunches all of the numbers together. Any idea how to style the results? 

Also Any thoughts on how to get the corresponding job name? 

Thanks so much!!

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi To set all the numbers from the array you can either access like he post on the answer with `[0]` for example or use [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi DaniP, is right with using a join.  To get the corresponding job name is a bit trickier... Your best bet would be in using objects.

Comment: @wateriswet Thanks for the help! Good advice. Can you elaborate a little on the object idea?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi, well, you'd just create an array of objects. Each object would have a job name and value. e.g. `[{name:'Job1',value:2},{name:'Job2', value: 40}...]`. You could then use the same code as above to get the top 3 values. Although, you must change the sort callback to `function(a,b){a.value - b.value}`. And when you have the top 3 values, you can just access the job name, by looking at the attribute `name` e.g. `top3Arr[2].name`